# Java Web Application can not be installed on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: java

I could install a Web Application on my laptop both on Ubuntu Linux and Windows without any problem. But When I tried to install it on raspberry pi 3 raspbian platform I got such a problem.

[image]

I tried both versions of setup file, 32 bit and 64 bit. I checked java version. But I could not figure out what is missing.

Comment: Pure java is portable to the Pi as is, but if the application comes in 32 and 64-bit versions it contains [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) code and as per vaha's answer, unless it specifically says "ARM" assume these bits are compiled for an x86 (Intel/AMD) based machine.  It won't work.  This doesn't explain the odd characters in the output but that may be coincidental.

Comment: @goldilocks The weird output is consistent with a binary file being interpreted as a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute binaries compiled for x86 architecture on arm processors.